# Find last line of text in .jpg file

Tags: batch-file, encryption

As weird as the question sounds, I want to find the last line of text in a .jpg file using batch.
I am working on a .txt file encryption via batch. I want the program to encrypt the contents of a .txt and append them to a set .jpg.
I then want the program to retrieve the last line of the jpg file and decrypt it.
I have been successful with the first part but I can't seem to be able to retrieve the last line of the jpg file as text. Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: Would be easier if you just used a real [Steganography tool](http://imagesteganography.codeplex.com/).

Comment: @Squashman, Perhaps but I want to learn how you do things like that. That is one of the reasons why I am doing this - to get better at batch.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in (version.txt) do set line=%%x
```

This will set the last line of any file as `%line%`

Comment: I would be interested to see the final outcome by the way, good luck!

Comment: Great, I'm about to test it. If it does work, I would be more than happy to post a link to an instant download of the file if you want. No copyright, modify and distribute as you wish. I will however not include the decryption key to protect my encryption but I am sure you can make one in under 5 mins. :)

Comment: Hmmm, while you seem to have answered my question, I still can't seem to get my code to work. If you want to have a look at my code, here is a [link](http://snale.rf.gd/publicDownloadFiles/FileUnlockerNoKey.php). Also, if you want to upload your version of the file if you modify it please use this [link](http://snale.rf.gd/publicDownloadFiles/index.php).

Comment: Im not quite sure what your code is doing.. I figured you were using the copy method to copy a file and a picture to a picture, which results in the text being near the end of the file. Do you also have the text encoded? I think I would need to see the encrypter too.

Comment: I do encrypt the message @Mark Dodsons . I was considering putting a string at the start of the text to make the code simply find that specific string however i believe the issue is not finding the string but accessing the .jpg as text. If you need to see the full code I can update the link but i will change the key slightly, otherwise, what's the point of the encryption right?

Comment: Im just not seeing which line you use the for command I gave you?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is my latest copy of that file. hang on 1 sec, I'll update the file and you can download it in 2 minutes

Comment: I have now updated the link, please click [here](http://snale.rf.gd/publicDownloadFiles/FileUnlocker.php) to download the new version of the file. I still can't get it to work despite the fact that I used your method. I also included the key however it is slightly modified.

Comment: Could you add this under the for /f command? Just to see what comes out? `echo %line% & pause`

Comment: and it sets the final line to the variable `%line%`... I dont see that anywhere in your script either, if you want to decode the final line of the image and that line looks like: `1djdinsn` and your command looks like `decode 1djdinsn` then replace it with `decode %line%` Hope this helps

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting lost here now. When I put `echo %line% & pause` where you told me to, it prints out `ECHO is off`. Could you by any chance try to fix the copy you have from the link and then upload it to the link above? It might look like I'm avoiding work but this comment-chat is getting very long and I'm starting to get lost. I'm also relatively new to batch.

Comment: Odd, I'll be able to work on it tomorrow. It shall be fixed! Thanks for your patients, It took me a while to find a working for command so theres a chance I gave you the wrong one. The only thing is it is hard for me to test your program since I dont have the same enviornment

Comment: I have a theory though, maybe try adding `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` just before the for command and then `EndLocal` After the `echo & pause`? Sorry I haven't helped so far XD. Once I find out what works Ill explain why for you.

Comment: Realy, no need to apologise. So far, you seem to be the only one interested in answering my question. I'm very thankful indeed. Also, I believe there is a website where you can test out batch scripts. I will send a link if i find it. I will also try out your suggestion immediately :) .
EDIT: I couldn't find any windows 7 emulator online. I also tried your code. nothing changed, no new output in the console, the file output.txt remains unchanged. I thought that you may want the encrypter and cover.txt file also, so I have now uploaded them to my server and they're available below.

Comment: 404 page not found? :O

Comment: Ah, yes sorry, try [this](http://snale.rf.gd/publicDownloadFiles/) updated link. The files are as follows: FileUnlocker.bat, FileLocker.bat and cover.txt. Good luck and thank you.

Comment: Not doing anything when I click the boxes :O

Comment: I'm so sorry. It worked right before i pasted the link here, i will fix it ASAP

Comment: Ok, I gave up on my server as I just could not get it to work. I suspect a php version change caused it. Anyway, I put the file on pastebin now and here's a [link](https://pastebin.com/shYarmue)